# Chat has three personalities

Tags: bug, chat

1. Log in to Chat.SE
2. Go to user page
3. Leave https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms?tab=site&sort=active open in another tab

   (This is the list of chat rooms about your parent user's site, whatever your parent user is)
4. Notice shiny <kbd>change parent user</kbd> switch, play with it a few times
5. Go back to rooms-list tab and notice:

> [image: It's all sorts of messed up!]
>
> 1. I opened the tab with a parent user of Stack Overflow
> 2. I was never viewing Network
> 3. My parent user is now Stack Apps

In my judgement, #2 is a bug (that text should have displayed `Stack Overflow`; the rest of the page certainly did); #3 is merely unexpected (I didn't expect the list of rooms to change like that while I was gone), but if you're interested in putting up a signpost...